# hiernate, replace collection proxy with transient collection, is there a better way?

Tags: java, hibernate

For example, I get a small object graph:

```
user
user.someCollection
```

the  someCollection has been set to lazy. so, I get a collection proxy.

then, I want add an item to the collection,

```
user.someCollection.add(...);
```

If turn the session on, this action would load the whole collection before I add. so, I close the session. if I close the session, I cannot add items to the proxyed-collection, hibernate don't let me do this. so I replace the user.someCollection to a real collection:

```
user.someCollection= new HashSet<...>();
```

and I add item to this REAL collection and open a new session to save

```
user.someCollection.add(...);
session.save(user);
```

Is this OK, that is replace the proxy with real collection manually ?

or are there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion, i've done this type before, as a part of tuning hibernate, i had to come up with the following solution

somecollection is also a type of entity(POJO) say that entity is `SomeItem`.

So, instead of adding the items using `user.someCollection` path, you can create the  `SomeItem` object and save it to the DB. Doing so, you need not load the lazy collection of the user entity.

**Eg:**

```
Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
for(.....){
    SomeItem si = new SomeItem(value1,value2,value3);


    sess.saveOrUpdate(si);
}
```